# How to change time (Advanced Eastern Time) on Slackware 8.1

Tags: linux, sync, time, date

I have a linux (Slackware) machine and the time/date is like, June 23rd 2003, 10:00am (It's 11 here) and I am not able to set the time to have it correct.

I change the timezome to Montreal but the time is still wrong.

Is there a way to force it to sync with my domain controler or even another online NTP server?

Thanks,

David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ntpdate 0.pool.ntp.org
hwclock --systohc
```

Comment: I finally fixed it by reimaging the whole computer. Thanks for the info.